# How to get current date and time in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, date

As you may know it's highly recommended by WordPress to theme/plugin authors to don't change the WordPress timezone by PHP functions like [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

I addition to that you may receive wrong date and time values when you use php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function because of not setting default timezone by PHP.

I mean you may receive 10 for `date('G')` while the exact hour is 15 in the selected timezone in WordPress->Settings->General->Timezone option.

So what should you do if you need the correct date and time values in selected timezone for WordPress website?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### WordPress 5.3+

You can use [current_datetime](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_datetime/) function. It returns a `DateTimeImmutable` object with the timezone selected in WordPress general options. Then you can use `format` or other methods of the object to get your desired date and time.

```
$current_datetime = current_datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

### Prior to WordPress 5.3

You should use [current_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) function of WordPress instead of PHP date function for getting local date and time in WordPress. It will return correct value for you based on selected timezone in WordPress general options.

For me `current_time('G')` returns exactly 15 while PHP `date('G')` returns 10 which is not correct.

Hope it helps somebody since I didn't find related thread in the stackoverflow.

Comment: `current_time` is pretty much deprecated and should not be used in current WordPress: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 5.3, you can use [`current_datetime`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_datetime/) to get it correctly:

```php
$current_date_time = current_datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The result will respect the time zone defined in the `Settings → General → Time Zone` select field, in the WordPress dashboard.

See also the [available formatting options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

**Note:** please don't use `current_time`, [it's not recommended anymore](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install a plugin like [Shortcode for Current Date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-for-current-date/) to display the current time in your respective time zone. It also provides a great overview of various date and time formats.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [current_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) function of WordPress instead of PHP date function for getting local date and time in WordPress. It will return correct value for you based on selected timezone in WordPress general options.

```
 $Date_Time   = current_datetime()
```

Retrieves the current time based on specified type.

```
current_time( string $type, int|bool $gmt )
```

Retrieves the current time based on specified type.

**Source** :

> File: wp-includes/functions.php

```
function current_time( $type, $gmt = 0 ) {
// Don't use non-GMT timestamp, unless you know the difference and really need to.
if ( 'timestamp' === $type || 'U' === $type ) {
    return $gmt ? time() : time() + (int) ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

if ( 'mysql' === $type ) {
    $type = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
}
```

Comment: `current_time` is not recommended anymore. But your code references `current_datetime`, which is another function that is currently recommended. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_datetime/